# KeepAliveD Documentation

Tags: linux, networking, load-balancing

I am looking for a consolidated documentation for KeepAlieD. My apologies if this is not the right place to ask this question.

However, even after extensive googling for 2 days, i could not find a consolidated documentation for KeepAliveD.

e.g. from google, I found about `vrrp_script` and `track_script` directives of keepalivd. Then I found out some more by running `man 5 keepalived.conf`.

And I kind of figured out (really ?) few more directives by looking under `/usr/local/etc/keepalived/samples/`.

BTW, http://www.keepalived.org/documentation.html is just not helping.

I mean, there might be many more awesome features that might be supported by KeepAliveD. Where do I find those features documented?

KeepaLived is supposedly been here for more than 10 years. Then why am I finding it so difficult to reach the formal/official/whatever documentation for keepaLiveD.

I really love to RTFM, but I need the Manual for it.

Comment: What I would say to do, because I share your frustrations, is to open an Issue, or if you look through the code, make Comments and stuff in it, or attempt to add documentation. Open a Pull request, or issue, and put some pressure on them to add more relevant and up to date documentation. https://github.com/acassen/keepalived

Answer (score 3):

Turns out the most complete documentation, as they are, are in the form of a synopsis file for the keepalived.conf file.

For your distro it might be unpacked to

> /usr/share/doc/keepalived-x.y.z/keepalived.conf.SYNOPSIS

Or use the link to the file in the git project:
https://github.com/acassen/keepalived/blob/master/doc/keepalived.conf.SYNOPSIS

And of course the configuration samples you've already discovered.

This is by no means a "complete/consolidated" documentation, but it should include all the verbs possible in keepalived.conf

Answer (score 1):

The URL you referenced is the official documentation. If it's incomplete or not helping, you'll need to talk tot he maintainers of that site to address those issues, but that is the offical, blessed, sanctified, formal, certified, everything-else-ified documentation.

Comment: Most of the stuff @ http://www.keepalived.org/documentation.html is either deprecated or incomplete or the links not working at all .Thanks for your time.

Comment: Again... deprecated though it might be, it is the official site. Take it up with the keepalived maintainers.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm not quite grasping what your definition of "consolidated documentation" is, but you could try, in Google's search, typing the following:

```
vrrp site:keepalived.org
```

The link to the UserGuide is here:
[KeepAliveD UserGuide](http://www.keepalived.org/pdf/UserGuide.pdf)

Comment: Most of the stuff @ keepalived.org/documentation.html is either deprecated or incomplete or the links not working at all . The user guide you referred is first off a deprecated one. Besides, it does not have a lot of information which you would find otherwise by googling. Hence the "Consolidated/official" userguide/documentation/manual is what I am looking for. I don't want somebody's blog to reveal hidden features of Keepalived. Trying harder ... Thanks for your time.

Comment: There's more than a few projects that aren't getting the love they need.  Usually, my method is to contact the few people that head up that project and request updates or whatever tribal knowledge they might have that wasn't posted on their site.  I'll usually get a reply with something useful around 7 times out of 10.